# Why is this word boundary regex not matching

Tags: c#, regex

This is the sample text:

> Item 1 : 1. A method of operating.

This matches `1.`:

```
\b1\.
```

But this does **not** match `1.`:

```
\b1\.\b
```

I need to have an **exact match** for `1.` I am testing it [here](https://regex101.com/r/ARC0De/1).

Comment: It's not really clear why you need `\b` at all - simply `1\.` would already return the desired exact match.

Comment: I don't want to match something like `1.2`

Comment: The boundary between `.` and `[ ]` (space after the period) is _not_ a word boundary, so your specified regex behaves correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is not a word character. `\b` is checking **word** boundaries, i.e. boundaries between word and characters not considered to be part of words. Therefore you cannot expect `.` to be inside the "word" `1.` because these two characters do not form a word.

---

[Quick reference document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) describes `\b` as:

> The match must occur on a boundary between a \w (alphanumeric) and a \W (nonalphanumeric) character.

And `\w` is described as:

> Matches any word character.

If you check what a [Word character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#WordCharacter) is, you will find it includes Unicode classes **Ll [Letter, Lowercase]**;
**Lu [Letter, Uppercase]**;
**Lt [Letter, Titlecase]**;
**Lo [Letter, Other]**;
**Lm [Letter, Modifier]**;
**Mn [Mark, Nonspacing]**;
**Nd [Number, Decimal Digit]** and
**Pc [Punctuation, Connector]**.

But `.` has Unicode class **Po [Punctuation, Other]** which is not listed above.

So if you expect `\b` to match a word boundary in `1.`, it is right between `1` and `.`. This answers your question **Why**.

**Note:** .NET regex expressions should be preferably tested on testing sites dedicated to them like for example [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/). If you test your regex using PCRE regex flavour (like on the site you linked), you can get different results from .NET.